# Get type from a templated range

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-studio-2013, stl

#### TL;DR

Given `R` as a template argument, for `R` being `some_container<T>` or `T[]`, how to deduce `T`?

Possible implementation is `std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(r))>::value_type`, looking for something less verbose.

#### Elaborated

I'm trying to implement a wrapper around `std::accumulate` algorithm, so that instead of typing this:

```
std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, [](int x, int y) { return x * y; });
```

user can simply write this:

```
my::accumulate(v, [](int x, int y) { return x * y; });
```

So basically, `my::accumulate`, given an entity and an operation, is intended to call `std::accumulate` with the following arguments:

1. `std::begin()` from the given entity
2. `std::end()` from the given entity
3. default-constructed value as a starting point
4. given operation

I use free `begin` and `end` functions to allow function work on built-in arrays. The passed entity is thus a *range*. Here is my implementation:

```
template<class R, typename F>
auto accumulate(const R& r, F&& f) -> 
  typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(r))>::value_type
{
  using T = std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(r))>::value_type;
  return std::accumulate(std::begin(r), std::end(r), T{}, std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

It works fine. The only thing that bothers me is that ugly `std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(r))>::value_type` construction. **Is there a better way to get the type from the range?** Note that `R` does not have to be a container, so I cannot use `R::value_type`.

Please note, that I'm using Visual Studio 2013, so I can use most of C++11 and some of C++14.

PS. Any other comments on the implementation? Are there any drawbacks or implications?

Comment: What's wrong with `typename R::value_type`?

Comment: You could take some inspiration from the [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) library.

Comment: @juanchopanza `typename R::value_type` does not work with built-in arrays.

Comment: @Mikhail Yes, good point.

Comment: You can use `typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::begin(r))>::type` as an alternative but if you count the letters it's longer than your version. BTW, in your `using ` statement you forgot to put `typename`.

Comment: @Jagannath `remove_reference` was my first thought, but I think `iterator_traits` is more clear in this case. Concerning missing `typename`, `using` statement works without it. Not sure whether it is standard-compliant or Visual C++ feature.

Comment: It's relaxed in vc++ implementation. But required by the standard.

Comment: @Angew From the point of view of the original task, yes, you are right, `boost::accumulate` is almost what I need. But the question is still interesting.

Comment: @Mikhail Yes indeed. I meant more for looking at implementation of things like `boost::range_value`.

Comment: @Jagannath Is it? A `using`-based alias declaration cannot refer to anything else than a type. **Edit** yes it is, 14.6/5 (which gives the exceptions to `typename` necessity) does not list it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(r))>` to save a few keystrokes, but it isn't much better.

I suppose you want to implement more algorithms than just `accumulate`, in which case you can create an alias for the element type:

```
template<typename T>
using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(T{}))>::value_type;

template<class R, typename F>
value_type<R> accumulate(const R& r, F&& f) 
{
  return std::accumulate(std::begin(r), std::end(r), value_type<R>{}, std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Otherwise, you could use a placeholder return type to avoid the repetition:

```
template<class R, typename F>
auto accumulate(const R& r, F&& f) 
{
  using T = typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(r))>::value_type;
  return std::accumulate(std::begin(r), std::end(r), T{}, std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Comment: First option is covered in the comments. Second -- in the question body.

Comment: @Mikhail The question body doesn't mention type alias nor placeholder return type. The first option uses a c++14 helper class which was not mentioned in the comment, which makes it slightly more concise.